# How to create a sub label with Gmail REST API

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the Gmail REST API to create a label (using my own code, not a library).  I have it working fine for a top level label, but now I want to create a sub label to the top label.  I noticed that when I create a sub label using Gmail, then look at the list I receive via the REST API, sub labels are shown using the '/' character as a delimiter, e.g. "Top Label/Sub Label".  However when I try to create a label like this, I just get a label that has the slash in the name, not an actual sub label.  How can I do this?

Comment: Note that this behavior has little to do with the API: When you create a new label in the UI called `a/b` without `a` already exiting, you only get one new label named `a/b`. If `a` already exists, Gmail sees it as the sublabel `b`. Guess `/` is simply a special character. Same in the API, it is just poorly (read: not) documented. It seems sublabels arent really an existing entity; just a way of displaying `/`-delimited labelnames

Answer (score 6):

You need to make two API calls. The first to create the top level label, the 2nd to create the child label. Once both labels exist, Gmail UI will properly collapse the label hierarchy.

Comment: So, create "Top Level" first - then create "Top Level/Sub Level" ?  I will give that a try.

Comment: No association necessary, just create a label called "Top Label" and then create a label called "Top Level/Sub Label".

Answer (score 2):

this is using python, and using MakeLabel and CreateLabel from here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/create

this is easy!..

```html
if papa_label_dont_exists:
    gmail_label_obj  = MakeLabel('Father')
    label            = CreateLabel(service, "me", gmail_label_obj)

gmail_label_obj  = MakeLabel('Father/Son')
label            = CreateLabel(service, "me", gmail_label_obj)
```